# How do I skip a for loop iteration if a condition is met when iterating through multiple files in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dynamic

I'm using os and glob to create a list of CSVs first and then using a simple for loop I go through all the files in the path applying my code.

```
path = r'my path'
os.chdir(path)
FileList = glob.glob('*.csv')

for fname in FileList:
Session = pd.read_csv(fname, header = 3, usecols = [0, 1])
Session = Session[Session['System'].str.contains('Day', na=False)]
Session = Session['No System Name'].tolist()
CRFs = sum(["CRF" in x for x in Session])
...
df.to_csv(path + 'test_' + fname , index = 0)
```

Is there a way I can make the loop skip a file if the length of Session equals to CRFs the loop will just stop and restart with the next file in the FileList?
I've tried doing it like this using both break and continue but neither did anything:

```
for fname in FileList:

Session = pd.read_csv(fname, header = 3, usecols = [0, 1])
Session = Session[Session['System'].str.contains('Day', na=False)]
Session = Session['No System Name'].tolist()
CRFs = sum(["CRF" in x for x in Session])
if CRFs == len(Session) is True: 
    continue(or break)
...
df.to_csv(path + 'test_' + fname , index = 0)
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Make use of `continue`?  Like `if <your condition> is True:  continue`.

Comment: I've tried that in a bunch of different ways but it doesn't seem to work. I have about 200 lines of code after the pd.read before the point where it would potentially need to skip based on whether the number of specific elements in one list matches the length of another list

Comment: I didn't get you. So is `continue` not working as expected?  or you aren't able to apply it with your condition? And when you say you want to skip, you want to discard everything you did until then in that loop and move to next right?  Maybe edit your question with more details of what you are doing and what you want.

Comment: Sorry I'll try to be more clear, `continue` is doing nothing when used as you suggested and my knowledge of Python's fundamental principles is insufficient to figure out why that is (I tunnelvision-learned pandas to specifically help me solve data processing issues for my lab research having no prior coding experience). Yes your understanding is correct, I want it to stop what it's doing and move on to the next file. I've edited the original question so hopefully it's a bit more clear now

Comment: I have replied in answer. Check if it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of below in your code:

```
if CRFs == len(Session) is True: 
    continue
```

Just do:

```
if CRFs == len(Session):
    continue
```

Comment: [More information about why this is the case.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_is.asp#:~:text=The%20is%20keyword%20is%20used,two%20objects%20are%20100%25%20equal.)
"The test returns True if the two objects are the same object.

The test returns False if they are not the same object, even if the two objects are 100% equal." - w3schools.com

Comment: @John Paul R answer gives you good explanation of how `continue` works. Go through the link he provided to understand more on loop constructs.

Comment: Thank you both for excellent information, these are the kind of knowledge gaps I'm trying to bridge. I found the official Python documentation to be the opposite of helpful as it often explains concepts in a way that adds complexity rather than removing it, w3schools looks like a great reference source. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I believe the [continue](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement is exactly what you are looking for.

When executed, the `continue` statement will cause execution of the current loop iteration to end, and the next iteration to begin.

Example from the python docs:

```py
>>> for num in range(2, 10):
...     if num % 2 == 0:
...         print("Found an even number", num)
...         continue
...     print("Found an odd number", num)
...
Found an even number 2
Found an odd number 3
Found an even number 4
Found an odd number 5
Found an even number 6
Found an odd number 7
Found an even number 8
Found an odd number 9
```

Comment: I've tried to get it to work a bunch of ways but I couldn't really figure out how to adapt it to my case (either getting syntax errors or just nothing happening), there are 200 lines of almost purely pandas code that only refer to fname for loading the file into the loop and saving the file at the end of the loop. Could it be that I need to somehow explicitly refer to the object of the for loop (which in this case is fname) in order for it to work???

Comment: Broadly, what you want is `if condition: continue`. I can't be more specific than that without seeing your code.

Comment: I've changed the example to mirror my original code, hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can *break* the main cycle when some condition happens, take a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) regarding this topic.